# Is it possible to have multiple subjects in Observer pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

I've been working on the Observer pattern, with a one-to-many event. In this case, are multiple classes notified, i.e. more than one observer from one subject?
Conversely, could there be more than one subject that I want to ask? Does this situation exceed the Observer pattern and create a different pattern?

Imagine a publishing house that prints *newspapers*, *magazines* and *books*. Users can subscribe to whatever they want. For example, a user might subscribe only to *books* or to *books* and *newspapers* at the same time. Each time a new one of these types is released, the relevant users should be notified. Users who are not registered should not be notified. In other words, if the user is only registered for *books*, a notification will not be sent for *newspapers*.

In this example, is the subject the publishing house? Or would *books*, *newspapers*, and *magazines* be separate subjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Observer pattern is intended for one-to-many notifications. In fact the first sentence in the chapter of the GoF book is,

> Define a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically.

The obvious solution is to make the publishing house the subject. My preference in this scenario is to have the subject fire different types of events and allow observers to register separately for each type of event they are interested in. It is also possible to fire a single event type and force the observers to determine what change occurred.

Alternatively, you could treat each individual publication as its own subject. In this scenario, as you mention, observers must register with different subjects. The only advantage I see here is that you can keep the observers decoupled from publications they needn't know about.

Both options are viable. I would recommend the publishing house as the subject.

Comment: The GoF book does actually mention the case of observing multiple subjects ("Observing more than one subject", p. 297). See also here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4829657/3160284). So as to the OP's question, this would probably not constitute a new design pattern.

Comment: I agree. The word, "alternatively" was not meant to imply an alternative pattern, but rather an alternative implementation of the same pattern. As published in the GoF book, Observer is quite broad. An intense debate over whether it should be split into multiple patterns resulted in just one. The debate is documented in [Pattern Hatching](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201432935). Had the debate gone another way, my preference from above (where one subject fires different types of events) would be called _Multicast_ rather than Observer. As it stands, both options qualify as the Observer pattern.